# Java String.format two decimal places with points as thousand seperators and a comma as the decimal seperator

Tags: java, string, format, decimal

I need to format a float with exactly to decimal places, "." as the thousand seperator and "," as the decimal seperator, like this: "1.234,56"

I have tried `String.format("%,f", myFloat)` but it gives me too many decimal places like this: "1.150,000000". Also, `String.format("%,2f", myFloat)` didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class to format your numbers as you wish :

```
float number = 12344.12f;

DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(','); // to be sure it is ','

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

String format = decimalFormat.format(number);

System.out.println(format);
```

The output is :

```
12.344,12
```

**EDIT**

For fixed decimal places try this :

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(','); // to be sure it is ','

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.###.00");
decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

String format = decimalFormat.format(number);
```

Comment: That's good, but I need the output to always have two decimal places.

Comment: I just realized I can say `decimalFormat.setMinimunFractionDigits(2);` to always get 2 decimal places. Thank you very much.